# How do I compile latest Parsley framework for Flex from SVN

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, parsley

How do I compile from the Parsley framework repository to a Flex Library, so that i can use it with the latest 4.5 Flex framework? Step by step. Totally appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a ANT script in the sources you can launch to compile the project.

If you're still having issues with it, try the parsley forum, you'll probably get your answer there.

Out of curosity, what doesn't it work with the 4.5 SDK?

Comment: I wanted to compile using the builder. Well the swc they supply was not compiled with 4.5

Comment: Using Flash Builder you mean?

Comment: yeah compile the swc using a library project in flash builder.

Comment: You don't have any other choices than looking at the ANT scripts, see how the different modules are built (included sources, compiler options, ...) and try to mimic it in Flash Builder.
It will be probably be long and painfull :)
BTW, it will probably work on a 4.5 project even it has not be compiled with that version